# How can I create html like table using iphone programming?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display HTML-like table data on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061156/how-to-display-html-like-table-data-on-iphone)

I need to create table like HTML table not something like  UITableView . 
So that I can show much data on main table .How can I create such table?.

Comment: hello you can create table using html the following code shows how to create a table

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTML table and show it in UIWebView - it will render HTML content.

Comment: but i need to go on detail page by tapping the items

Comment: You can listen for JavaScript events that occur in a UIWebView.

Comment: In this case, you can put an hypertext link on the cells and catch it in the UIWebView delegate (webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) to open the detail page.

Comment: please post some example code

Comment: --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671742/send-a-notification-from-javascript-in-uiwebview-to-objectivec

Comment: hello You can create a table in webview by using html you can use the

Answer (score 0):

I found this framework which contains DTGridView control.

[DTKit](https://bitbucket.org/danielctull/dtkit/wiki/Home)

Maybe it is simpler that reimplement everything.