# HTML with icon on left and right side

Tags: html, css

I want to create an un-order list in html. Each of list item, there will be an icon on left side and an icon on right side. The text is among 2 icons and should auto occupy available screen width. In the case of long text, it will be ellipsis. The list item should like this:

```
++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++
+icon+ + short text             + +icon+
++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++

++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++
+icon+ + long text long text ...+ +icon+
++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++

++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++
+icon+ + short text             + +icon+
++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++
```

I tried many ways to create the list but didn't success. Please help! Any solution or recommends are welcome.

UPDATE: I need the icons on separated tags, such as `div` or `img`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: give us some code of what have you tried

Comment: will the icons have all the same width/height?

Comment: Yes, all icon will have same size

Comment: I know why no one mentioned the word table!

Comment: @EmmadKareem I tried to use `display:table` before, but when I ran the page on iOS webkit, the first column always occupy a half of available space. Do you have any example of this?

Comment: I don't know about iOS but maybe this is related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061156/how-to-display-html-like-table-data-on-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use floats: [Demo 1](http://jsbin.com/ohoyoz/1/edit)

And you can use position absolute: [Demo 2](http://jsbin.com/efareg/1/edit)

Ignore if it's not what you are after.

Comment: Nice example, but the text is wrapping around the icon, right? I want the text and icons are separated columns.

Comment: Hi Adaz. I saw that your solution worked when ran on JSBin. but, when I try on google chrome or iOS webkit, It didn't.

Comment: Let's talk your code through on the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29416/html-with-icon-on-left-and-right-side

Answer (score 2):

Just combine some CSS tricks:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    background:url(http://www.caloriedagboek.nl/_lib/img/icons/icon_help.gif) right center no-repeat;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 24px 0 0;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
li:before {
    content:url(http://www.caloriedagboek.nl/_lib/img/icons/icon_help.gif);
    margin:0 0.5em;
}
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCnU2/).

Comment: Great help. But there is any way to separate the icons into independent tags? such as `img`

Comment: As discussed below - you could for the first icon (just move it inline and remove the `:before` declaration). For the second one it's not possible since the ellipsis would cut it off. You could however simply do it from HTML by setting `style="background-image:url(...)"` on the `<li>` element for the second icon. There are more complex solutions that would allow putting both in `<img>` tags, those would severely complicate matters and require positioning hacks though.

Comment: This means that we can add separated `img` at right side if the text isn't ellipsis any more?

Answer (score 1):

you can take advantage of `calc`

maybe something like this.

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSfty/1)**

Comment: what is it that it is not addressing?

Comment: In my Chrome (beta channel) it runs outside the right screen border. Admittedly I only saw just now that that was the reason I didn't see the second icon hehe, fixed my comment.

Comment: @Niels add `box-sizing:border-box` to `ul`

Comment: Still you didn't handle the ellipsis requirement, and not sure you can easily do it when the images are part of the markup since it'll clip the right image first. Another challenge?  ;)

Comment: @Niels i didnt see the ellipsis requirement. you win. :)